# Is it possible to create an executable file with just copying the text segment?

Tags: c, executable

When you run a C program, is it possible to get its binary code (which you execute with `./foo`) from its TEXT segment? If I just copy all the TEXT segment to a file, then can I execute it and run the same program? I am working with Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "copy all TEXT segment to file"?

Comment: The code depends on data which isn't in the code segment. And the executable file is not only the different segments, there's also a lot of other meta-data for the file to be considered an executable "program".

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE For example create file `foo_copy` and write all TEXT segment into it. If i already execute ./foo, than it has /proc/$PID/mem file which contains all binary instructions. And in case that all that instructions is just a copy of the binary  of 'foo' program that maybe it is possible to  copy all instructions in other file and get the same program? So by that phrase i mean - copy eac byte from /proc/$PID/mem file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it possible to get it binary code

If you run your program under the debugger, then you can copy the bytes from anywhere in the process space, being data or code.

> then i can execute it and run the same program?

Simple answer: No!
An executable file is a lot more than just a memory dump.

Comment: maybe you also know: is it possible to disassemble running process? Something like `objdump -d` do, but for running process. In my C program i working on, i need to get disassemble file of other running process

Comment: This is another question. StackOverflow requires you to create a new question.

Comment: okey, i will. But i have 90 minutes timeout to write next one :)

Comment: `disassemble running process` that's what a debugger does...

Comment: thanks, i understand, but can i run debugger (GDB or something else) from C program and create with this an output file? Then i will need that file to pars it and find some functions start addresses.

Answer (score 1):

If your program is static-linked and position-dependent and has no global data (note: the last is not true with **any** non-toy libc implementation), then in theory the text segment is sufficient to run it. However, you would need an appropriate loader to do so. Normal operating systems' executable file loaders do not load this kind of "raw text segment" as an executable because (1) is has no header information to indicate that that's what it is, or even where to start execution at (i.e. what's the entry point), and (2) it's not generally useful to do so. DOS had something akin to this with `.COM` files, and uClinux had `FLAT` binaries that were close to this but with some minimal header, but those are the closest you'll find to a "raw text segment" binary in the past 3-4 decades.

Answer (score 0):

there is the link with familiar question
[Is it possible to dissembler running process in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67450168/is-it-possible-to-dissembler-running-process-in-linux?noredirect=1#comment119219977_67450168)

```
char *comp = "objdump -d /proc/1234/exe";

fflush(NULL); // always useful before system(3)
int nok = system(comp);
if (nok) {
    fprintf(stderr, "compilation %s failed with %d\n", comp, nok);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

So what i want is a `/proc/<PID>/exe` file.