# Is it possible to dissembler running process in Linux?

Tags: c, debugging, process, disassembly, objdump

To disassemble the program I am using `objdump -d` tool. Is it possible to get the same output as with `objdump` for running process without condition to have `exe` file? How can i do it in `C` language from other program? I know that exists debuggers like `GDB`, but I need to use that functionality in `C`. As result of my program I want to get output file with disassemble functions for running process. I have an PID of process. I am working with Ubuntu.

Comment: `objdump -d /proc/<PID>/exe` ?

Comment: @dratenik Thanks so much!! you really save lots of time for me. I have tried objdump -d /proc/<PID>/mem before but it was not working, `exe` file is what i need

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to get the same output as with objdump for running process without condition to have exe file?

Yes it is, because i have PID and the file i need is located `/proc/<PID>/exe`

To call that in C i will try something like that:

```
char *comp = "objdump -d /proc/1234/exe";

fflush(NULL); // always useful before system(3)
int nok = system(comp);
if (nok) {
        fprintf(stderr, "compilation %s failed with %d\n", comp, nok);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Thanks for [@dratenik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14215102/dratenik)!